# SyntaxError when using jQuery.html to insert HTML fragment containing script element

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

I am using jquery ajax request which gets the HTML content from backend code. If status is OK, I am appending HTML content to a div. I am using following code to append div using jquery ajax. as `$('#divElm').html(response.data);`. But after appending I am getting following error:

> SyntaxError: missing } in compound statement

The HTML content rendering from backend (ie., response.data) contains the following which is causing this error:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function init() {
if(d.getElementById('normal')){
    window.normalPop= d.getElementById('normal');
    //complicated is local 
    var complicated= normalPop.parentNode.removeChild(normal);
    d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(complicated);
    }
}   
addLoadEvent(init);
</script>
```

I am not sure why this error "SyntaxError: missing } in compound statement" is coming.The } braces are closing properly in the code.

If I am using `innerHTML` instead of `html()` it is working fine. No error is rendering.

Comment: Your code doesn't show any jQuery - are some parts missing?

Comment: @MarcoK It's there - `$('#divElm').html(response.data)`, where `response.data` is alleged to *contain* the big section of posted code.

Comment: How is this "too localized"? It's a common problem in Jquery - Jquery can trigger an error because of script included in it. The solution is to have a try-catch around the `.html(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

The.html() uses .append() which inturn uses domManip() which does the script sniffing and execution. Because of this reason, the script code in coming from backend executed and caused this error "SyntaxError: missing } in compound statement".
I investigated through the script code, the comment lines (//) in script code make commented some JS code too.So, after changing single line (//) to multi-line comments(/** **/).It get fixed.Thanks All for your time.

Comment: had the same issue here, unbelievable, that a comment is the bad guy..